# Database with 40000+ records per day

Tags: php, database, database-design

I am creating a database for keeping track of water usage per person for a city in South Florida.

There are around 40000 users, each one uploading daily readouts.

I was thinking of ways to set up the database and it would seem easier to give each user separate a table. This should ease the download of data because the server will not have to sort through a table with 10's of millions of entries.

Am I false in my logic?
Is there any way to index table names?
Are there any other ways of setting up the DB to both raise the speed and keep the layout simple enough?

-Thank you,
Jared

p.s.
The essential data for the readouts are:
-locationID (table name in my idea)
-Reading
-ReadDate
-ReadTime

p.p.s. during this conversation, i uploaded 5k tables and the server froze.  ~.O
thanks for your help, ya'll

Comment: Another plus, when a user moves away, I can just drop their respective table.

Comment: Then how??? lol (don't make fun, this is the first time I'm dealing with this much data)

Comment: You've got like four fields to worry about. You don't need a whole new table per user for four fields.

Comment: sounds like you need more professional help than asking random strangers on the internet.

Comment: but i love you guys! lol I start school tomorrow, so I'll ask my old prof.

Comment: you're doing this and in school? how does South Florida hire people? picks randomly from phone book?

Comment: What is the exact use case you are trying to solve? You have a large amount of data coming in which will form part of the design - how the data is aggregated and displayed will determine the rest. Are there reports generated from this and are they on demand, is historical data included or just kept in case of further analysis. Does aggregation span days/locations.

Comment: @JohnD the uses of this system are 1) So a customer can compare their usage to others of the same type (residential, commercial, etc.) 2) So a user can be alerted if their usage drastically goes up and 3) so the company can be alerted of people using water when they're currently shut off.  Fluffeh made a good point when dealing with comparisons and totals.  Daily reads are necessary so we can get the information in hours, instead of at the end of the month.

Comment: @Dagon My school sucks and I can't afford any better. Plus, I want a major project on my resume. Once the schema is written, the product will probably be sold to the city (I'm thinking, "product sold to the government" wouldn't that look nice? lol).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting up thousands of tables in not a good idea. You should maintain one table and put all entries in that table. MySQL can handle a surprisingly large amount of data. The biggest issue that you will encounter is the amount of queries that you can handle at a time, not the size of the database. For instances where you will be handling numbers use `int` with attribute `unsigned`, and instances where you will be handling text use `varchar` of appropriate size (unless text is large use `text`).

**Handling users**
If you need to identify records with users, setup another table that might look something like this:

- user_id INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT UNSIGNED PRIMARY
- name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL

When you need to link a record to the user, just reference the user's `user_id`. For the record information I would setup the SQL something like:

- id INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT UNSIGNED PRIMARY
- u_id INT(10) UNSIGNED
- reading ***Im not sure what your reading looks like. If it's a number use `INT` if its text use `VARCHAR`***
- read_time TIMESTAMP

You can also consolidate the date and time of the reading to a `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: there would also be no primary key in that case. How can I work around that?

Comment: No keep an auto incrementing primary integer with length of 10 or so.

Comment: If you give me additional details I can tailor my answer to them.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Dealing with the schema, there is a lot more data, such that each user can have multiple locations, contacts, billing information, etc. but that was taking care of. I was planning on having a table of customer information point to which locations they own (a Customer Id can point to multiple Location IDs). I will definitely keep a separate (single)table for that data. Once again, thank you.

Comment: the reading rolls over at 1M gal (9 digit positive int). One thing that I was reading is that it is hard to search by date using a timestamp. [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp) (at the bottom)

Comment: @Jared The lower granularity your date/time is, the faster the search for matching records will be. If you just need the date that the record was entered then use `DATETIME` with YYYY-MM-DD. However, if you think that the search will begin to get slow than you can split the time the record was entered into two fields, `date` and `time`. Under date store the `DATETIME` above, and under time store the H-M-S. But, when it comes time to searching for records only search within the date column. And then allow user to narrow search by hours, minutes, and/or seconds.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15592/discussion-between-glenn-dayton-and-jared)

Comment: When talking to my brother, it seemed like no one would have any use for the time of the reading. But, there might be a use later on, so I decided to include it. (There is only one reading per day, when it was received is a technicality of the retrieval system)

Answer (score 5):

Do *NOT* create a seperate table for each user.

Keep indexes on the columns that identify a user and any other common contraints such as date.

Think about how you want to query the data at the end. How on earth would you sum up the data from ALL users for a single day?

If you are worried about primary key, I would suggest keeping a LocationID, Date composite key.

Edit: Lastly, (and I do mean this in a nice way) but if you are asking these sorts of questions about database design, are you sure that you are qualified for this project? It seems like you might be in over your head. Sometimes it is better to know your limitations and let a project pass by, rather than implement it in a way that creates too much work for you and folks aren't satisfied with the results. Again, I am not saying *don't*, I am just saying have you asked yourself if you can do this to the level they are expecting. It seems like a large amount of users constantly using it. I guess I am saying that learning certain things while at the same time delivering a project to *thousands* of users may be an exceptionally high pressure environment.

Comment: >How on earth would you sum up the data from ALL users for a single day?  Very good point    The end queries were just for one particular customer to look up their usage, but there is a possibility that we might want to implement a comparison operation.

Comment: @Jared Use the SQL function `SUM`.

Comment: @GlennDayton I meant how would he sum them up if the data was in thousands of tables.

Comment: @Fluffeh This is my first project; a learning project. Working on it with my brother, pro bono.  "...delivering a project to thousands of users may be an exceptionally high pressure environment." -thats why i want to do it right. :-)

Comment: @Jared I am glad that you want to do it right, I am just trying to say in a nice way that learning to *do it right* and *doing it to a deadline* are often conflicting goals. I admire the idea, just want to ensure that you aren't put in a position that you aren't happy with. I find that learning how to do something is best done by taking your time, going through things at a slow pace and best done without a waiting audience. Still, I do certainly wish you the best of luck and will happily answer more questions if you ask them.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking tables should represent sets of things. In your example, it's easy to identify the sets you have: users and readouts; there the theoretical best structure would be having those two tables, where the readouts entries have a reference to the id of the user.

MySQL can handle very large amounts of data, so your best bet is to just try the user-readouts structure and see how it performs. Alternatively you may want to look into a document based NoSQL database such as MongoDB or CouchDB, since storing readouts reports as individual documents could be a good choice aswell.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a summary table that contains the monthly total per user, surely that would be the primary usage of the system, right?

Every month, you crunch the numbers and store the totals into a second table. You can prune the log table on a rolling 12 month period. i.e., The old data can be stuffed in the corner to keep the indexes smaller, since you'll only need to access it when the city is accused of fraud.

So exactly how you store the daily readouts isn't *that* big of a concern that you need to be freaking out about it. Giving each user his own table is not the proper solution. If you have tons and tons of data, then you might want to consider sharding via something like MongoDB.

Comment: Two implementation of this system are: 1) to inform users if their daily usage exceeds a limit set by their previous usage (leaks) and 2) see if anyone is using water after they have been shut-off (stupid that the company doesn't already have this) - which needs daily data

Comment: @Jared, 1) could be part of a monthly (or whatever the billing period is) sum and 2) could be a real time check. Really neither of those use cases _demand_ that you persist data on a daily basis. e.g., You could simply update a monthly total on a daily basis. You have to draw the line somewhere, after all. (Why not log every hour or minute or second?) But that said, I'd probably log daily and keep a monthly total for faster access and reports.